# Net core parallel request cause multiple db calls

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a application with n tier and web service architecture.

6 web server with customer application and api application.

My problem is, when users requested to my frontend application normally my frontend requests to api. But when api makes the frontend wait a little bit, customers can click same button twice or multiple times.

Normally this web context doesnt diasppear and same stored procedure called twice or more times.

Can u offer some suggestion or implementatin for this problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually handled on the front end . When user click the button to send ajax , you can set an on-click method to set the attribute of the button to `disabled` and when ajax return normally remove the attribute.

When Api need more time to process the data , you can use `CSS Masking` to prevent the user from clicking the button multiple times.

Here is a link about how to use [`CSS Masking`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_masking.asp).